# Getting rows of a table in single record

Tags: sql

I am completely new to programming 
I have a table with 2 column Key(Integer) and Values(Containing comma separated string) 
for example below

```
Table A
  Key   Values
  1     1,2
  2     3,4
```

I have another table again with 2 columns Key(Integer) and Value(single integer value)

```
Table B
  Key   Value
   5     4
   6     7
   7     2
   8     8
```

I am trying to get a all the Keys from table B whose values are not in Table A.
 Something like below .

```
Select * from B where Value not in (1,2,3,4)
```

Any suggestion or help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered reading a tutorial?

Comment: Read this->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: That will tell you how to split the comma-delimited values. You can then use those values in your `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tableA` is in a *very* bad format.  You are storing numbers as strings, instead of in a native format.  Worse, you are storing lists in a string variable.  SQL has a very useful mechanism for storing lists.  It is called a table.  The particular table structure you would want in this case is a junction table.

That said, sometimes you are stuck with data in this format.  Let me assume that is true here.  You can approach this by doing something like this:

```
select *
from tableb b
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablea a
                  where ',' || a.values || ','  like '%,' || b.value || ',%'
                 );
```

This is quite inefficient compared with a version using a junction table.

Also, this uses `||` to concatenate strings.  This varies by database.  It could be `+`.  Or `&`, or even just the `concat()` function.